# Passing parameterized Class instance to the constructor

Tags: java, generics

I have lost in the Jungle of Generics, please help me :) I have something like this:

```
public class BaseClass<TYPE> {
    public BaseClass(Class<TYPE> clazz) {};
}

public class FirstLevelClass<REFRESHABLE 
    extends RefreshableInterface> extends BaseClass<REFRESHABLE> {

    public FirstLevelClass(Class<REFRESHABLE> clazz) {
        super(clazz);
    };
}

public class Argument<T extends AnyOtherClass> 
    implements RefreshableInterface {

    public refresh() {}
}

pulbic class ProblematicClass 
    extends FirstLevelClass<Argument<AnyOtherClassDescendant>> {

    public ProblematicClass() {
        //Compiler error: Constructor 
        //FirstLevelClass<Argument<AnyOtherClassDescendant>>(Class<Argument>) is undefined
        super(Argument.class); 
    }
}
```

As far as I think, the compiler should accept `Argument` since it implements `RefreshableInterface`.

- Why do I get this error?
- How can I make the `ProblematicClass` working?

ps: if you have better title for this, please change it. I could not make up better.

Comment: Which error you are getting? And please provide all the necessary classes that you're using in bounds.

Comment: @RohitJain It's in the comment.

Comment: I don't have the availability to check in an IDE right now, but I think the problem is that you have a mismatch between your type argument `Argument<AnyOtherClassDescendant>` and the bare `Argument.class`.

Comment: Objects of type `Class` always refer to the class itself and not a generic type, since generics are a compile-time idea and reflection is run-time. Furthermore, that `Class` instance has to be valid for all specializations. So passing around `Class` objects for generic types can get tricky, and generally is a bad idea. In my experience, it typically means you are trying to do something that is not supported by the language and should be accomplished some other way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Issue is, your constructor expects a `Class<T>`, and `T` in your code is inferred as `Argument<AnyOtherClassDescendant>`.

So, you should pass a `Class<Argument<AnyOtherClassDescendant>>`, and you're passing `Class<Argument>`. But you can't pass that `Class` instance directly, as you cannot do `Argument<AnyOtherClassDescendant>.class`.

You can however, solve the issue by typecasting the class to required instance:

```
public ProblematicClass() {
    super((Class<Argument<AnyOtherClassDescendant>>)(Class<?>)Argument.class); 
}
```

Note, how you've to typecast `Class<Argument>` first to `Class<?>`, and then the resultant type to `Class<Argument<AnyOtherClassDescendant>>`. There is no simple way to achieve that.

The reason behind this is, there is only a single `Class` instance for all parameterized instantiation of a generic type, that is associated with the class itself. A single compilation unit of a generic type, compiles to just a single class file. I guess this is different in how C++ implements templates. There you get different machine codes for different instantiation.

So, if you execute the below code, you'll get `true` as output:

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

boolean isSameClassInstance = strList.getClass() == intList.getClass();
System.out.println(isSameClassInstance);
```

Comment: I knew this would require some serious handwaving at the compiler. Is there any better reason why you have to do this and not just `Argument<AOCD>.class` than That's The Way It Is?

Comment: @chrylis Because `Argument<AOCD>.class` is not valid. You cannot use `.class` literal with any parameterized instance, but only raw types.

Comment: Right; I'm asking if you know if there was a reason why Sun did that or if their imagination just failed, because it seems like the Right Answer for cases like this.

Comment: @chrylis That is because, all the parameterized types share the same `Class` instance. And that is associated with the class itself, and not with any particular parameterized instantiation. Since there is only a single compilation unit for all the instances of a generic class, it makes sense to only have a single `Class` instance for that class. This is a bit different in how `C++` implements templates. It creates separate machine code for each instantiation. contd...

Comment: So, in Java, if you try to do - `new ArrayList<String>().getClass()` and `new ArrayList<Integer>().getClass()`, you'll get same output - `class java.util.ArrayList` for them.

Comment: +1 Note that narrowing the generic type of a `Class` token is not always safe, because `Class.cast` cannot check an object's generic type. In this case it's probably fine though.

Comment: @PaulBellora That is true. In fact, this is the only use case, where I've ever used such kind of type-casting. :)

Comment: I'm aware of how erasure works, but because of that very fact the error is a compile-time error that could have been avoided with parameterized literals.

Comment: @chrylis You might want to go through [this faw link](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ106) for some more sensible reasoning. But I guess you won't be satisified with that too. Problem is, there is no correct answer to - Why this was done like that in Java? Well, there can always be various way to do something. But, it's upto Java designers as to what they chose. Perhaps, they wanted to keep it simple, as allowing `Class` instance for various parameterized types, wasn't buying them anything, as they represent the same thing.

Comment: Works like it should. I would not have made up this double casting on my own. Thanks for the explanation. I still think, that the compiler could be clever enough to accept this without casting, but I can live with that.